# Retrieve data from HugeClob in oracle

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I have one Table, in this table stored data as xml on `HugeClob`. In this xml I have several data. I want retrieve this data with SQL query. I add 3 xml example.

```
//  First 
<xml-fragment>
  <sdr:OCAC>
    <op:operation>Sale</op:operation>
    <op:ID>100</op:ID>
    <op:payload>
      <op:Tea>
      </op:Tea>
    </op:payload>
  </sdr:OCAC>
</xml-fragment>

//  Second 
<xml-fragment>
  <sdr:OCAC>
    <op:operation>Sale</op:operation>
    <op:ID>101</op:ID>
    <op:payload>
      <op:Cofe>
      </op:Cofe>
    </op:payload>
  </sdr:OCAC>
</xml-fragment>

//  Third 
<xml-fragment>
  <sdr:OCAC>
    <op:operation>Sale</op:operation>
    <op:ID>102</op:ID>
    <op:payload>
      <op:Juice>
      </op:Juice>
    </op:payload>
  </sdr:OCAC>
</xml-fragment>
```

I want shown query result as attached image. I'm so sorry for my english.

```
Tea's price is 1.50
Cofe's price is 2.50
Juice's price is 3.00
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Put a valid xml sample and namespace definition, Price not available in above sample. See below how we can fetch xmltags as columns.
SELECT ExtractValue(column_value, '/xml-fragment/OCAC/ID') AS ID, ExtractValue(column_value, '/xml-fragment/OCAC/ID')
                      FROM TABLE(XMLSequence(XMLTYPE('<xml-fragment>
 <OCAC>
  <operation>Sale</operation>
  <ID>100</ID>
  <payload>
   <Tea>
      </Tea>
  </payload>
 </OCAC>
</xml-fragment>
').extract('/xml-fragment')));